# Apache spark custom log unfiltered data (LazyLogging)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm filtering a column to comply with some validations and I can filter using Spark built-in functions,
**but** I need to log the invalid data with a proper message (I am using LazyLogging), is there any way I can do it without using a custom UDF, so I can keep Spark optimization?

for example filtering names that are shorter then 20 characters:

```
df.filter(length($"name") <= lit(20))
```

in this scenario how can I log the names that are more than 20 characters without custom UDF?

Answer (score 0):

In case the result of the filter operation is not too large that it does not fit into your driver, you can collect the result and print it out to your default Logger.

```scala
val logCollection = df.filter(length($"name") > lit(20)).collectAsList
logCollection.foreach(logger.info(_))
```

As an alternative you can create a separate stream by applying another writeStream format to write the names into a database, console etc. Just keep in mind that when you do this, you will actually create multiple streaming queries within your SparkSession which are consuming the data independently:

```
val originalDf = df.[...]
val logDf = df.filter(length($"name") > lit(20))

val originalQuery = originalDf.writeStream.[...].start() // keep logic as is
val logQuery = logDf.writeStream.format("console").[...].start()

spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

Comment: well,
the filter operation gives me the name's under 20 characters and I am trying to log the longer names.

Comment: Then just use the complementary filter condition?

Comment: yea but then I  will need to cache the data frame and run a separate filter only to retrieve the invalid results. it will create unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I would not call it "unnecessary" as long as you have the requirement of logging it.

Comment: I think that in this case custom UDF will be better in this case because then I can log the invalid names and return the valid names.

Comment: I think so too. Depending on the amount of expected invalid names it may be the easiest way to apply a UDF.